# Can I install 3-way switches using two 14/2 cables with another switch for a separate light?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

There are 2 boxes. Box 1 has the source power and box 2 has an unrelated second switch and fixture. Here is a diagram of what I am working with. Is it possible to have a 3-way using this setup?

[image: diagram]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The installer thought they could use 2 cables to get 4 conductors.  Not allowed per 300.3(B) due to AC magnetic effects (the same thing that makes transformers work that makes it even possible for the general public to have electric power.)

Use smart switches which use either wireless or powerline signaling, such as Intsteon... and then you can do this.

[image]

Black = always-hot
White = neutral
Red = switched-hot 1
Blue = switched-hot 2
You don't have to use colored tape to designate conductor *by function*, but [it's cheap](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Gardner-Bender-1-2-in-x-20-ft-Colored-Electrical-Tape-5-Pack-GTPC-550/100054213) and it makes boxes a lot less confusing.

Comment: Aha! I was thinking smart main in box 1, smart remote in box 2. Your way means the 2nd cable isn't needed at all.

Comment: @manassehkatz However it requires a careful choice of smart switch.

Answer (score 3):

#### Sorry, but no, not with normal current wiring practices

You have 4 wires that need to make it from box 1 to box 2:

- Travelers (2) for the 3-way switches
- Hot for the outdoor light
- Neutral for all the lights

You have 4 wires. But they are not combined properly. The problem is that the neutral needs to include all the return current for all matching hots. That gives you two options:

- 3 wires for the 3-way switches - traveler 1/traveler 2/neutral **and** 2 wires for the outdoor light - this would be a /3 cable plus a /2 cable. **But you have 2 14/2**.
- 2 wires for the 3-way switches - traveler 1/traveler 2, hot for the outdoor light, and **neutral combined together with both the travelers and the hot**. That would be a /4 cable. You have 2 /2 cables, so your neutral only gets to combine with the hot (or one traveler) and not with everything.

End result is, this won't work, except possibly using **Smart Switches**.

There are plenty of smart switches that use **one traveler** instead of 2. If you can find one where it only requires two wires - switched hot & neutral - then you can use a 14/2 for the 3-way switch, with the 2nd 3-way switch likely being a battery-powered remote and not a wired 3-way switch, and the other 14/2 is used as a standard hot/neutral to the switch for the outdoor light.